# MYSQL Query: combine columns and get count

Tags: mysql

I have about 9 tables that contain the same type of field. I would like to combine the 9 of them FIRST, and then get the distinct count of unique values in that combined column. This is what I've tried so far, but to no avail. I'm not also not sure this is the most efficient way to return this value?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT aircraft_id) FROM 
(
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.a_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.b_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.c_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.d_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.e_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.f_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.g_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.h_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.i_message
) ;
```

Comment: Why do you have these separate tables and not just a single table with a column to indicate the 'type' of message?

Comment: I'm fairly noob when it comes to schema design, so this could be a matter of combining all the aircraft_id values into unique values in a table, then referencing the associated data in the other tables on a foreign key?

Comment: Hard to say without understanding what the data is intended to represent...

Comment: I will say that in total aircraft_id values can reach in the millions in terms of rows for each table, but in total only a small fraction of unique aircraft_id values exist across all tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT aircraft_id,count(aircraft_id) FROM 
(
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.a_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.b_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.c_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.d_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.e_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.f_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.g_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.h_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.i_message
) group by aircraft_id;
```

or

```
select aircraft_id,count(aircraft_id)
(
SELECT DISTINCT aircraft_id FROM 
(
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.a_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.b_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.c_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.d_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.e_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.f_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.g_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.h_message UNION ALL
SELECT aircraft_id FROM database.i_message
)
) group by aircraft_id;
```